# What cause thread unsafe but nothing shared across threads?

Tags: thread-safety

I am new to learn multi-thread programming. I am told that thread - unsafe problem is always caused by something shared across multi thread. That makes sense for me, however, that seems can not explain the issue in below code which appears nothing is shared across multi thread.

```
package test;
public class Outputer{
    
                public void output(){
                    String name = "123456789";
                        int len = name.length();
                        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                           System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    
                }
        }
```

```
package test;

public class TraditionalThreadSynchronized {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outputer outputer = new Outputer();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    outputer.output();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    outputer.output();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

what I expected is that `123456789` should be seen intact. But sometimes, I can see the output in console as below.

```
... ...

123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789     // expected
112323456789 // unexpected
456789       // unexpetecd
123456789   
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
... ...
```

I understand the root cause is that when one thread is executing code snippet below, its cpu time segment is over so thread is not able to finish execution. Another thread get cpu time segment then start to execute below code snippet but also possible to not finish the execution. then first thread again get cup time segment then continue to execute from where it was stopped.

In a word, I am aware that the root cause is below code snippet is not Atomic operation.

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
 System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println();
```

My fix is to surround with synchronized block as below. Now it reaches my expectation. Looks good.

```
 synchronized(this) {
                            
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
     System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
   }
   System.out.println();
 }
```

However, I still have some doubts which is currently haunted my mind. Somebody help !!!

Is the statement below true ?  Always ?

> the thread - unsafe problem is ALWAYS caused by something shared across my multi thread

I am asking because I don't see any data shared across threads in my example. The variable `name` is local variable, not a pass-in parameter or pass-out parameter (returned parameter). So `name` is thread safe.

If the statement is true, what is shared by threads ?

If the statement is false, any other situation can caused thread unsafe without sharing data across threads ?

Comment: "something shared" includes resources like the console, open files, the display, other resources.  Not just data.

Comment: Thanks for reply @DaveS.
Just a double confirm that you mean that statement is true and in my example, the thread unsafe issue is caused by shared console, correct ?

Comment: @AndyLi, Yes. `System.out` is shared between the two threads. And whether or not there is a "thread-unsafe problem" is a matter of opinion. The two threads each send one character at a time to `System.out`, and probably all of those characters are being printed. Somebody might say that proves there is _no_ problem. On the other hand, if you have an expectation that the characters will be grouped in a certain way (e.g., each thread gets exclusive use of `System.out` while it prints a whole line at a time) then you will need to make them talk to each other in some way to coordinate that.